# Clangd does not see declarations unless the header is included in the file, despite it being included correctly for compilation

Tags: c, clangd

I am writing a project in C and I run into a problem where clangd doesn't really see declarations that are included before the header file in main.c(I am doing a monobuild, so a single translation unit).
I prefer to have all my includes in main.c so I don't have to start every single file with a bunch of includes. I know I can create something like basic.h for the most common headers, but I still don't need to do that if I can just include it once on top of the main file.
Is there a way to tell  clangd(and make it permanent if at all possible) to take into an account how the headers are actually used?
Example

```
// someheader.h
u64 foo(u64 bar) { ... } // clangd complains about u64 there
// main.c
#include "stdint.h"
typedef uint64_t u64;
#include "someheader.h"

int main(void) {
  foo(1);
  return 0;
}
```

I am using clangd with vscode if that's changes how to set it up.

I tried to google it, and I couldn't find anything about how to do it, but I may have not phrased it very well. There is a related question about whether you *should* do this, and it concludes that it's a matter of preference, so it doesn't really answer my question.

I've got responses saying it's not a good idea, which I can't really confirm or deny, but even if it's definitely bad, I've seen it done in multiple open source projects, and I'd still like to read them without putting in the work to hunt down all the headers and definitions it actually uses.

Comment: What do you mean by "parent file"? Each `.c` file is compiled independently, they all need to include the declarations they need. There's no hierarchy of `.c` files.

Comment: Sorry if I phrased it poorly. I meant that main.c includes it in a particular order so by the time the header is included all it needs is already declared. I am doing a monobuild so I won't have more then one translation unit anyways.

Comment: A header file shouldn't depend on its caller to define a typedef. Why does `someheader.h` need to use `u64` when it could just use `uint64_t`?

Answer (score 2):

All source files and header files should include the files necessary for their dependencies.

It is bad practice to have to depend on files being including in a particular order because of said missing dependencies.

So in your particular case, that means these two lines:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint64_t u64;
```

Must be included in someheader.h.

Also, it's bad practice to have function implementations in header files, as doing so can lead to errors related to multiple definitions.

Comment: Why would that be a bad practice though? I am not writing a library, they all will be used in exactly one project in exactly one order. Anyway it is really common to see it being done in the wild, and even if it is a bad practice, I still would like to read the code without 1000 compiler errors.

Comment: @kayak It doesn't matter that it's not a library.  Dependencies being moved around can make your code fragile.  Being common doesn't mean it's a good idea, and you won't see any compiler errors if you build your code correctly.

Comment: @kayak - Also, at some point, you're going to want to write libraries to reuse your code, even if that's just copying files around and rebuilding them everywhere.  Or you'll want to use unit tests, which won't be able to use your `main.c` (probably).  Or you'll want to use linters and static analyzers, which will run faster if you target specific files as you make changes.

Comment: @dbush I am not a professional c programmer and maybe it is a really bad idea in practice. But as I said, I've seen multiple big opensource projects being done this way(xcb comes to mind), and I'd really like to be able to read them with an editor support

Comment: @kayak And you can get that support by including the necessary headers that the file requires.

Comment: @dbush So every time I want to read source code of such a project I am supposed to hunt down all the headers it actually uses, just to paste it even if it does have everything it needs for compilation? Why?

Comment: @kayak If you're reading code, you don't need to hunt down the headers.  They should already be there if the code was built properly.  Only if you do it your way will you need to hunt down the required headers.

Comment: @dbush the example I've given is in fact compiling. And as I said, I've seen projects that do it this way, or similar so it's still a problem there

Comment: @kayak Only because it depends on the headers being placed in a particular order.  Any header should be able to be used in any source file *by itself*.

Comment: @kayak And again, just because others do it doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: @dbush I am not trying to argue with that. I don't have experience shipping a c program to verify that. But it doesn't really matter in the case of reading other projects, as I don't have a control over them, and I still want to read them comfortably.